# Excel formula-based lookup for multiple criteria across multiple sheets?

Tags: excel, indexing, lookup

I have a series of tabs formatted uniformly that contain data that I want to consolidate onto one master data sheet. I'd like to do this without indexing/looking up each sheet individually.

I've created a sample to illustrate the challenge I'm having in searching for data across multiple tabs to create a master data dump. Given the 4 worksheets shown below, the *Summary* tab has pre-filled values and I'm trying to fill in for the values marked with `???` if possible.

**John:**

```
         | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3
---------------------------------------
Sales    | 500     | 1000    | 800
Expenses | 200     | 300     | 250
Total    | 300     | 700     | 550
```

**Joe:**

```
         | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3
---------------------------------------
Sales    | 400     | 800     | 600
Expenses | 300     | 280     | 225
Total    | 100     | 520     | 375
```

**Mary:**

```
         | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3
---------------------------------------
Sales    | 750     | 850     | 900
Expenses | 275     | 325     | 400
Total    | 475     | 525     | 500
```

**Summary:**

```
Agent | Period  | Sales | Expanses | Total
-------------------------------------------
Joe   | Month 1 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
Joe   | Month 2 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
Joe   | Month 3 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
John  | Month 1 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
John  | Month 2 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
John  | Month 3 |  ???  |    ???   |  ??? 
Mary  | Month 1 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
Mary  | Month 2 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
Mary  | Month 3 |  ???  |    ???   |  ???
```

Comment: This data architecture is set up the wrong way. The data should be ENTERED into the master sheet, for all people. Then you can build a report to show the data for each person. Golden rule of spreadsheet design: Data in one sheet, reports in other sheets.

Answer (score 0):

In your sample, the detail sheet data fits exactly in the summary, except that it is transposed.  If this is the case for the actual data as well, you may be best off if you `copy` each chunk of detail data (3x3 in sample) and then `paste special - transpose` in succession (in case it helps `transpose` is a check box which appears on the `paste special` dialog).

Answer (score 0):

I like Steve Klein's answer for simplicity and ease of understanding.  Here's an alternative if you really need it to be dynamic.  "Sales", "Expenses", "Month1", "Month2", etc. as well as "Joe", "John" & "Mary", need to be exactly as in the detail sheets and the detail sheet names.

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT($B2&"!"&"$A$1:$D$6"),MATCH(D$1,INDIRECT($B2&"!a:a"),0),MATCH($C2,INDIRECT($B2&"!3:3"),0))
```